# (VisualStudio) The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable

Tags: visual-studio

Trying to simply install latest VS 2017 Community Edition in Windows 10 but get a popup error

[image]
Common error but have tried all suggested solutions including

1) Clean Boot

2) Running the "Microsoft Fix" Diagnostic tool

3) Running VS2017 Installer as administrator with Repair option

4) Uninstalling VS 2015 first

5) Installing VS 2015 first

6) Running vc_redist.x86.exe

7) Running vcredist_x64.exe

8) Tried uninstalling EVERYTHING related to visual studio using Revo Uninstaller and then reinstalled VS 2017

But I STILL get the popup error. Actually the same error on #'s 3,5,6,7,8 above!! Can anyone help?
Geesh, installing software shouldn't take 3 days googling...

The VS error log shows the following

> Package 'Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.11.25325,chip=x86'
>   failed to install.
>       Search URL
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1603
>       Details
>           Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14,version=14.11.25325,chip=x86\VC_redist.x86.exe"
>   /q /norestart /log
>   "C:\Users\art3mis\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170815135802_001_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log"
>           Return code: 1603
>           Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
>       Log
>           C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170815135802_001_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.log
>       Impacted workloads
>           Game development...

Comment: Op...think I FINALLY solved issue. Used MS FixIt tool to manually UNINSTALL ALL MSVisualStudio C++ packages one by one ...then turned off my Antivirus protection and did a repair using VS2017 installer. Only about 8 hours to install:)

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and accept it.